# How to stack on top of each other an image+text

Tags: html, css

In my HTML I have an image inside of a section and text aligned to it. The div is wrapped in a blue line for clarity.

I want to repeat this div 5 times (as I need to put 5 players). However, no matter how much I try, the second player's div overlaps with the first player's div.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="keywords" content="navi, csgo, team, esport" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web oficial NaVi">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="comu.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icona" type="image/ico" />
</head>

<body class="bodyweb">

  <header class="header">
    <img id="imgheader" src="newbanner.jpg" alt="Navi" />
  </header>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="portada.html">Introduction</a>
    <a href="history.html">History</a>
    <a href="team.html">Team</a>
    <a href="news.html">News</a>
    <a href="awards.html">Awards</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </nav>

  <section class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="columna1team">
        <img id="s1mple" id="imgplayers" src="s1mple.png" alt="Navi" />
        <p> Natus Vincere, or just NAVI, was founded over 8 years ago by the
          merging of two rosters and since then the team has become a household
          name in Counter-Strike. The team has a rich history and an overflowing
          trophy cabinet, living up to the Latin translation of the team’s name
          – “born to win”.</p>
      </div>
      <!--div columna1-->
      <div class="columna2team">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#s1mple">Entry</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#formacioAcademica">Support</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#experienciaLaboral">IGL</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#dadesInteres">Rifler</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#dadesInteres">AWPer</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--div columna2-->
    </div>
    <!--div content-->
  </section>
  <footer class="bottom">
    <img id="imgfooter" src="footer.png" alt="Navi" />
  </footer>
</body>
```

and my CSS:

```
/*team*/

.columna1team {
  width: 67%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.columna2team {
  width: 29%;
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#imgplayers {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 1%;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
}
a:link {
  color: #a7d7bf;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: #648172;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #62ff62;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  color: #62ff62;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some images of how your webpage looks, so we can directly suggest to you what should you do to fix the error...

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by `the second player div gets inside the first player div.` ~ possibly do a screenshot? Also - which DIV ( or element ) do you wish to repeat 5 times ( columna1team ? ) ?